# Groups for replacements not seen by `sre_parse`

Tags: python, regex

I've just discovered the module `sre_parse`.

Is it normal that the following code doesn't take care of the group `\g<TEST>` which can be used to do replacement in a match ?

```
import sre_parse

pattern = r"(?P<TEST>test)\s+\w*\g<TEST>"

parsedpattern = sre_parse.parse(pattern)
parsedpattern.dump()
```

This gives the following output where all the last literals should be, from my humble point of view, indeed something giving informations about a replacement to be done.

```
subpattern 1 
  literal 116 
  literal 101 
  literal 115 
  literal 116 
max_repeat 1 2147483647 
  in 
    category category_space
max_repeat 0 2147483647 
  in 
    category category_word
literal 103 
literal 60 
literal 84 
literal 69 
literal 83 
literal 84 
literal 62
```

Comment: Does Python support Oniguruma recursion calls?

Comment: @sin: no it doesn't but in Python `\g<1>` is a simple backreference as `\1`

Comment: `\g<TEST>` is Pcre specific Oniguruma recursion call. In Pcre, I think your regex would be equivalent to `(?P<TEST>test)\s+\w*test`

Comment: Indeed I'm looking for something telling me that a pattern used `\g<...>`.

Comment: Then in that context, the pattern is no different than `test\s+\w*test` There is no way the pattern can't use \g<...>, its not optional. I guess you could wrap it in another group. `(?P<TEST>test)\s+(\w*\g<TEST>)`

Comment: I have finally give a partial answer just below. I will look for another way to find the use of `\g<...>`...

Comment: @sln I have no control in the pattern... It will be build by other people.

Answer (score 0):

### There is no bug

I've take a look more closely in the documentation. Here is another code.

```
import sre_parse

pattern = r"(?P<TEST>test)\s+\w*\g<TEST>"

parsedpattern = sre_parse.parse(pattern)
parsedpattern.dump()

print('---')

pattern = r"(?P<TEST>test)\s+\w*(?P=TEST)"

parsedpattern = sre_parse.parse(pattern)
parsedpattern.dump()
```

This prints the following output where we can see that the group is seen in the 2nd pattern but not in the 1st one.

```
subpattern 1 
  literal 116 
  literal 101 
  literal 115 
  literal 116 
max_repeat 1 2147483647 
  in 
    category category_space
max_repeat 0 2147483647 
  in 
    category category_word
literal 103 
literal 60 
literal 84 
literal 69 
literal 83 
literal 84 
literal 62 
---
subpattern 1 
  literal 116 
  literal 101 
  literal 115 
  literal 116 
max_repeat 1 2147483647 
  in 
    category category_space
max_repeat 0 2147483647 
  in 
    category category_word
groupref 1
```

The documentation says that `\g<...>` can be used in a string passed to the `repl` argument of `re.sub()`. This is certainly this function that does the replacements.

So I will have to look for another way for searching `\g<...>` in a pattern...

Comment: Oh, I see, your debugging the regex. `*(?P=TEST)` is a Python backreference. But, `\g<name>` is normally a recursive call in PCRE. You could try other traditional backrefs `\k<name>` or `\g{name}` used in different engines. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm making a tool to find easily recursive groups by defining the opening and closing delimiters with regexes. Some closing delimiter uses text found in an opening delimiter like in this XML example `<a> ... <b> ... </b> ... </a>`. In that context, the user of my program will use `"<(?P<attribut>\w+)>"` for the opening delimiters, and `r"</\g<attribut>>"` for the closing ones. I'm working on tools to verify the good use of `\g<...>`.